# Increase size of the system partition

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

On my Windows 10 PC, I have a 465.76 GB disk of which (in that very order) 390.18 GB are System (C:), 450 MB are Recovery, and 75.14 GB are unused.

I now want to increase the size of C: but from `diskmgmt.msc`, I cannot do anything with the Recovery partition, and it blocks my way.

Do I have a possibility to increase the size of the system partition, using only Windows tools?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done while the system is running.

To achieve what you want to do you must boot from Recovery/Installation media such as a Windows 10 USB or DVD and use it to modify the partition table while your install is offline.

**NB:** As always, back up before doing anything potentially destructive like this.